# github-for-mac not opening any windows on yosemite

Tags: git, macos, github-for-mac

I have just installed the latest github from [here](https://mac.github.com/). I completed the first launch successfully and added a local repository. After that, github didn't open the main window. I tried 'create new repository' as well as 'clone to Desktop' from the web, to push it to open the main window, but failed. Absolutely nothing opens except 'preferences'.

Any ideas on why might that be?

Comment: What happens when you choose the File->New Window menu item?

Comment: Nothing happens. I deleted the application and re-added it, still nothing opens!